# Convert DataFrame to Array of Objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to convert a Pandas DataFrame into an array of objects (something that is more 'comfortable' to work with in JavaScript)?

I am using Facebook Prophet to run a timeseries forecast and return the data back to the client to do something with it.

I essentially want to take a DataFrame like this:

[image]

But, return something like this:

```
[
    {
        'ds': <value>,
        'trend': <value>,
        'yhat_lower': <value>,
        'yhat_upper': <value>
        ...
    },
    {
        'ds': <value>,
        'trend': <value>,
        'yhat_lower': <value>,
        'yhat_upper': <value>
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

I have tried `DataFrame.to_json()` which is kind of close to what I need, but it presents other issues. I also tried `DataFrame.to_dict()` and that isn't really what I want either. Same story fo `DataFrame.to_records()`

Do I really need to loop through the `DataFrame` manually to build up the list how I want it or is there some parameter/method I'm missing on getting a DataFrame to format as an array of objects with column names as the object key's?

**UPDATE**

`.to_dict()` is close to what I want, but there's still a nested object. Is there a way to get rid of that?

```
{'additive_terms': {0: 1821.6658106578184},
 'additive_terms_lower': {0: 1821.6658106578184},
 'additive_terms_upper': {0: 1821.6658106578184},
 'daily': {0: -904.5939055630084},
 'daily_lower': {0: -904.5939055630084},
 'daily_upper': {0: -904.5939055630084},
 'ds': {0: Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00')},
 'multiplicative_terms': {0: 0.0},
 'multiplicative_terms_lower': {0: 0.0},
 'multiplicative_terms_upper': {0: 0.0},
 'trend': {0: 3959.7525337335633},
 'trend_lower': {0: 3959.7525337335633},
 'trend_upper': {0: 3959.7525337335633},
 'weekly': {0: 1382.1213748832024},
 'weekly_lower': {0: 1382.1213748832024},
 'weekly_upper': {0: 1382.1213748832024},
 'yearly': {0: 1344.1383413376243},
 'yearly_lower': {0: 1344.1383413376243},
 'yearly_upper': {0: 1344.1383413376243},
 'yhat': {0: 5781.418344391382},
 'yhat_lower': {0: -4262.772973874018},
 'yhat_upper': {0: 15333.709906373766}}
```

**UPDATE 2**

It looks like @busybear's answer is what I want, however, I want it as an array of objects instead of a large object using the index as the key to the individual record:

```
{0: {'additive_terms': 1821.6658106578184,
  'additive_terms_lower': 1821.6658106578184,
  'additive_terms_upper': 1821.6658106578184,
  'daily': -904.5939055630084,
  'daily_lower': -904.5939055630084,
  'daily_upper': -904.5939055630084,
  'ds': Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
  'multiplicative_terms': 0.0,
  'multiplicative_terms_lower': 0.0,
  'multiplicative_terms_upper': 0.0,
  'trend': 3959.7525337335633,
  'trend_lower': 3959.7525337335633,
  'trend_upper': 3959.7525337335633,
  'weekly': 1382.1213748832024,
  'weekly_lower': 1382.1213748832024,
  'weekly_upper': 1382.1213748832024,
  'yearly': 1344.1383413376243,
  'yearly_lower': 1344.1383413376243,
  'yearly_upper': 1344.1383413376243,
  'yhat': 5781.418344391382,
  'yhat_lower': -4262.772973874018,
  'yhat_upper': 15333.709906373766},
 1: {'additive_terms': 1609.1847938356425,
  'additive_terms_lower': 1609.1847938356425,
  'additive_terms_upper': 1609.1847938356425,
  'daily': -904.5939055630084,
  'daily_lower': -904.5939055630084,
  'daily_upper': -904.5939055630084,
  'ds': Timestamp('2016-01-02 00:00:00'),
  'multiplicative_terms': 0.0,
  'multiplicative_terms_lower': 0.0,
  'multiplicative_terms_upper': 0.0,
  'trend': 3954.608221609561,
  'trend_lower': 3954.608221609561,
  'trend_upper': 3954.608221609561,
  'weekly': 1056.9172554279028,
  'weekly_lower': 1056.9172554279028,
  'weekly_upper': 1056.9172554279028,
  'yearly': 1456.8614439707483,
  'yearly_lower': 1456.8614439707483,
  'yearly_upper': 1456.8614439707483,
  'yhat': 5563.793015445203,
  'yhat_lower': -4892.457856774376,
  'yhat_upper': 15305.24188601227}}
```

Comment: It's close. It comes back with a nested object which is what I don't want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try This:

```
df.to_dict('records')
```

It gives you a list of dictionary without the index.

Comment: This solution is shorter than busybears and gives the same result. I think this makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 3):

`to_dict` sounds like what you want actually. How is it not working for you? You could transpose your dataframe and take just the values of the dictionary. that will match what you expect:

```
data = df.T.to_dict()
list(data.values())
```

Comment: Even closer! Is there a way to kill the index and make an array of objects rather than one large object with the index as the key?

Comment: @mwilson can you print a sample please, would be helpful

Comment: Is that not accomplished with `values`? That will take just the values of the dictionary and not the keys. You may want to convert it to a list since it's a `dict_value` object.

Answer (score 0):

To do so:

`df.to_json(orient="records")`

That should get you to exactly what you need.  Other orientations are `split`, `index`, and `table`.

For more information, see: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html